# Python loads MongoDB data very slowly

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I use both MongoDB and MySQL in same database. It takes less than 0.3~5 seonds to read MySQL data which has more than 20 rows. However, it takes 1.0~1.5 seconds to read MongoDB data which has less than 10 rows. Is this normal??

Here is Python codes for loading MongoDB data and show result on HTML

```
collection = db.announcements
result = collection.find().sort('reg_date',-1)
cnt = collection.find({},{'_id':0}).count()

results = []
for index in range(cnt):
    results.append({"title":result[index]['title'], "message":result[index]['message'], "reg_date":str(result[index]['reg_date'].year)+"-"+str(result[index]['reg_date'].month)+"-"+str(result[index]['reg_date'].day)})
    flash(result[index]['title'],'title')
    flash(result[index]['message'],'message')

return render_template('admin/dashboard/notice.html', length = len(results))
```

I wonder what is problem.. I tried to pass all data right away to HTML page, but I failed. I had to reorganize data and put it in array in right places.

Comment: How exactly have you timed the mongo queries? Did you time the `collection.find()` calls or the dictionary building and flashing *after* the data is loaded?

Comment: @NeilLunn this is indeed an exact duplicate, even from the same poster

Comment: Please use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of `range()` and `index`.

Comment: @frostnational Yes, I do understand. I couldn't get answer from another question. That is why I posted again. Is there a way to let others know unsolved question?